# run hadoop based on the sources generated from maven

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to make some changes on the hadoop framework but i am stucked in setting up my development environment. I have cloned hadoop from git and generated all the java projects to import to eclipse with maven as explained here [EclipseEnvironment](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment). After importing all projects in eclipse i generated a normal java project which should run a job in hadoop and i set two project dependencies for hadoop-common and hadoop-mapreduce-client-core on the build path of my project and all dependencies were resolved.

When i run the project i get the error

```
2013-05-23 12:58:01,531 ERROR util.Shell (Shell.java:checkHadoopHome(230)) - Failed to     detect a valid hadoop home directory
java.io.IOException: HADOOP_HOME or hadoop.home.dir are not set.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName.<clinit>(PlatformName.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getOSLoginModuleName(UserGroupInformation.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2512)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal(FileSystem.java:323)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:86)
2013-05-23 12:58:01,546 INFO  util.Shell (Shell.java:isSetsidSupported(311)) - setsid exited with exit code 0
2013-05-23 12:58:01,730 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2013-05-23 12:58:02,065 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation (UserGroupInformation.java:doAs(1492)) - PriviledgedActionException as:elma (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1277)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:100)
```

So how can i please make the new java project run based on the hadoop source projects i have in eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

Since your question is "How can I run hadoop based on the sources generated from maven?", I will assume that you've been able to successfully run vanilla Hadoop. If you have, then you just need to copy your own jars (generated via eclipse or using maven in the command line) and replace the jars of your vanilla Hadoop distribution (same version). This should do the trick and save you time from dealing with configuration issues.

Comment: oh i meant it the other way round. I work with eclipse and now have all the hadoop projects in my workspace. Is it now possible to run hadoop without generating jars for replacing the original ones but run it directly in eclipse. So i can test every change i make to the code and see errors in the console without the need for generating jars, copying them and look at the logs ;)

Comment: Ah, got it. I've never worked that way, so I can't give any pointers to do what you want to do.